# Yajra multi search filters

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am trying to assign a custom search box for each column of the table as shown in this example.

https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/multi-filter-select

But the code given for this was so confusing. I am not getting any idea how to use that code to achieve this.

Here is my code.

> CONTROLLER FUNCTION

```
function leadManage(Request $request){
    $lead_id = $request->get('id');
    echo $lead_id;
    if ($request->ajax() && $request->draw) {

        $data = lead::select('leads.id', 'leads.fname', 'leads.lname', 'leads.phone', 'leads.email', 'leads.created_at', 'lead_status_lists.status_name', 'users.fname as user_fname', 'users.lname as user_lname');
        $data = $data->join('users', 'leads.assigned_to', '=', 'users.id');
        $data = $data->orderBy('leads.id', 'DESC');
        $data = $data->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('date', function($row){
                    $date = date('d M Y', strtotime($row->created_at));
                    return $date;
                })
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="'.url('admin/update-lead/'.base64_encode($row->id)).'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-r-5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil font-14"></i></a>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete" onclick="return deletelead_conf('.$row->id.')"><i class="fa fa-trash font-14"></i></button>';

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['name','user_name','date','action'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('admin.lead_manage');
}
```

> View File script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.dataTable').DataTable( {
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: "{{ route('lead.index') }}",
      columns: [
        { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false },
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
        {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'course_name', name: 'course_name'},
        {data: 'user_name', name: 'user_name'},
        {data: 'status_name', name: 'status_name'},
        {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
      ]
  });
  
});
```

I tried to add additional script from given url but it make table body empty and no error. Here is script from given url which I tried to add.

```
initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function () {
                column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
            });
        });
    }
```

But I am not getting any idea how to use those controller function (from given url) in my written code.